# How to show date properly retrieved from database, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, date, ejs

i've been busy on a project for school to make an app using Node.js and a mysql database. I got stuck at showing the date properly i was retrieving from the database. This is the code for showing the data from the EJS file:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Titel</th>
        <th>Locatie</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Waardering</th>
    </tr>
        <% } %>

        <% for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>

        <td><%= pictures[i].titel %></td>
        <td><%= pictures[i].locatie %></td>
        <td><%= pictures[i].datum %></td>
        <td><%= pictures[i].naam %></td>
        <td><%= pictures[i].waardering %></td>
        <% } %>
    </tr>                   
</table>
```

This is what i get:

[data from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSQuv.jpg)

I just want to show the day, month & year

Thanks for your help

Comment: Add a JSFiddle so we can give you the working code. I don't want to write that date from your picture....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have valid ISO dates that can be passed directly to `new Date`.

In your route, parse the dates with something like this before you send it to the template

```
app.get('something', function(res, req, next) {

    var pictures = get_from_mysql('something');

    pictures.forEach(function(pic) {
        var date  = new Date(pic.datum);
        pic.datum = date.getDate + '/' + (date.getMonth + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    });

    res.render('template.ejs', {pictures:pictures})

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! had to figure some out, but I get it going now :)